# como recupero el valor que tengo en mi BD de un Radio button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<div class="imptText">
   <div>
      <input type="radio" id="req" name="req" value="<?php echo $fila['evidReq']; ?>"/> si<br/>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="radio" id="req" name="req" value="<?php echo $fila['evidReq']; ?>"/>no  <br/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Si lo hago así, el value va a ser si siempre, quiero que me retorne el valor que esta chekeado.

Esta solución le di

```
if($fila['evidReq']=='si'){?>                                                    
  <input type="radio" id="req" name="req" value="si" checked /> si<br/>
  <input type="radio" id="req" name="req" value="no"  /> no<br/>
<?php }else{?>
  <input type="radio" id="req" name="req" value="si"  /> si<br/>
  <input type="radio" id="req" name="req" value="no" checked /> no<br/>
<?php } ?>
```

es optima?

Comment: Puedes ser más preciso por favor

Comment: Si es buena, pero se puede mejorar. Debes cambiar las ID. Las id son unicas, los name se puedenb repetir

Comment: En el caso de los `radio` siempre se recibirá el valor del elemento que esté chequeado. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer con esos datos en el servidor? Parece que te código es la pescadilla que se muerde la cola entrando en un ciclo interminable. Partimos de que hay unos radio en el cliente, eso es enviado al servidor, ¿qué debe pasar luego?